# How do i get a like button working in my expressJS app?

Tags: node.js, express

i'm trying to get a like button working n my website here's the code.[enter image description here][1]

```
router.put('/campgrounds/:id/likes',isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate('likes').exec(function(err,foundCampground){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('back');
    }else{
        foundCampground.likes.author.id=req.user.id;
        foundCampground.likes.username=req.user.username;
        foundCampground.likes.push(req.user.username);
        foundCampground.save();
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + foundCampground.id);


    }
});
```

});

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

var likeSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    author:{
        id:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:'User'
        },
        username:String
    }
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Like',likeSchema);

var campgroundSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
image:String,
imageId:String,
description: String,
createdAt:{type:Date,default:Date.now()},
author:{
    id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    username:String
},
comments: [{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Comment'
}],
likes: [{
    type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'Likes'
}]
```

});

module.exports =mongoose.model('Campground',campgroundSchema);

I'm stuck here please help as i really need it to work. i can't seem to figure out the problem here.

Comment: What is wrong with it? Where is the button? Why does it not work? Update your question above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create or update (in ref to CRUD operations)?. It seems you are trying to create and should thus use 'post' rather than 'put'. Try using 'router.post' instead of 'router.put'.

```
router.post('/campgrounds/:id/likes',isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate('likes').exec(function(err,foundCampground){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('back');
    }else{
        foundCampground.likes.author.id=req.user.id;
        foundCampground.likes.username=req.user.username;
        foundCampground.likes.push(req.user.username);
        foundCampground.save();
        res.redirect('/campgrounds/' + foundCampground.id);

       }

    });
});
```

Comment: okk..but still in the console it says that'cannot read id of undefined'. i don't know whats happening. Actually i'm trying to get a like feature in my site. kindly help